# jQuery hover effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I am new to jQuery and trying to figure out how to use the `.hover();` effect in place of the `.mouseover()` and `.mouseout()` effects. Here is the scenerio:

I am using a table and want to highlight the row with a CSS class that changes the background color to a light yellow. Here is the CSS:

```
.bgHvr {
  background-color: #FFFACD;
}
```

The only way I know how to add the hover effect I desire is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#table tbody tr').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('bgHvr');
  });
  $('#table tbody tr').mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('bgHvr');
  });
});
```

UPDATE:

After some more help I found out a simpler way of a hover effect:

```
$('#table tbody tr').hover(function() { 
  $(this).toggleClass('bgHvr');
});
```

This is possible after the 1.4.2 update to jQuery which changed how the `.toggle()` effect worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hover basically combines the 2 events into one.

```
.hover(mouseover,mouseout)
```

or in your case:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#table tbody tr').hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('bgHvr');
  },function() {
    $(this).removeClass('bgHvr');
  });
});
```

Comment: ok thank you, now I understand. each function simply calls the "mouseover" and "mouseout" that is contained within `.hover`.

Answer (score 2):

Um...How about just using CSS?

```
#table tbody tr:hover {
    background-colour: #FFFACD;
}
```

EDIT: With ***[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hchLk/)***

Comment: It isn't fully supported in all versions of IE

Comment: this is way more efficient.  and supported by everything from IE 7 and up.

Comment: Fair enough but anything before IE7 shouldn't be supported anyway, in my opinion. IE6 is 10 years old and should be completely disregarded really.

Comment: @anothershrubery I agree with that comment completely. Unfortunately it isn't always a decission we can make as a coder. If something needs to be supported from IE6 onwards, then it has to be coded as such. Personally, I agree with everything you are saying.

Comment: I too want to drop support for browsers that don't follow CSS2/3 or HTML5.  Anyhow, since this is simply for effect you could get away with this depending how important the hover effect is.

Comment: I understand your reasoning on this and understand completely but I may need a hover effect for something more complicated that can't be achieved through CSS `:hover`.

Comment: @Reevine - You never mentioned that... ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#table tbody tr').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).addClass('bgHvr');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('bgHvr');
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way I know how and fully compatible with all browsers.

On an unordered list -

**JS**

```
$('ul').delegate('li', 'mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

**CSS**

```
li.hover {
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

Comment: I was not aware of the `.toggleClass` function. thank you for showing me this.

Comment: No problem! A lot of things toggle in jQuery - instead of show()/hide() think about when you can use .toggle() instead.

Comment: though out of curiosity why use the `.delegate` function and specify the child element? Could you also do this? `$('ul li').hover(function() {$(this).toggleClass('hover');});`

Comment: Yep you absolutely could do that.  Your way binds the event handler directly to the LI element.  The delegate method uses "event delegation" and binds only one handler to the UL (the delegate) which acts on the LI elements.  So if you had 1,000 LI elements, using your way you'd bind 1000 handlers but event delegation uses only 1.  It's probably not necessary if you only have a handful of LI elements.  Hope that helps!

Comment: so if im targeting a common element it would be safer to use delegation so it doesn't tax the javascript engine of the browser with all the handlers for the event?

Comment: Yep that's one of its benefits.  The other one (which you'll like) is that you don't have to rebind your event to dynamic elements that get added later.  If you add LIs to the UL they automatically get the event because the actual handler is added to its parent!  :p  Hallelujah!

Comment: Also, you can't do 'hover' in delegate/live methods since its not a real event.  Use 'mouseenter mouseleave' if you decide to go this route.

Comment: Well I am learning new things every minute and thank you for your wealth of knowledge.